# Swift: Make UIGestureRecognizer affect only one UICollectionViewCell instead of all

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with cells populated from my AssignmentManager class. When the user wants to delete an assignment, they press and hold a cell for a delete button to appear on the cell they clicked. With the code below, the delete button appears on every single cell when the user clicks on one. How can I fix this with UIGestureRecognizer? What do I do to specify the single cell that the user presses and holds in my code? Any help would be appreciated.

*Some things to note: I only included the code below that I think is relevant to the question. I can add more if needed. Also yes, I did misspell deleteButton as delteButton. I'm sorry if that confuses anyone.

```
    var userWantsToRemoveDeleteButton: Bool = false
    var userDelete: Bool = false

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
               let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! homeworkcell
               cell.delteButton.hidden = true
               cell.delteButton.enabled = false
                    if userDelete == true {
                        cell.delteButton.hidden = false
                        cell.delteButton.enabled = true
                        if userWantsToRemoveDeleteButton == true {
                            cell.delteButton.hidden = true
                            cell.delteButton.enabled = false
                        }
                    }
                    // add button gestures
                    cell.delteButton?.layer.setValue(indexPath.item, forKey: "index")
                    cell.delteButton?.addTarget(self, action: "deleteAssignment:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

                    // add the swipe gestures
                    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "deleteMode:")
                    cell.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)

                    let assignments = AssignmentManager.assignments[indexPath.item]
                    cell.myLabel.text = assignments.title
                    cell.assignment = assignments
                    cell.dueLabel.text = dateString
                    cell.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
                    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
                    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
                    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8

                    return cell
            }

    func deleteMode(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
            userDelete = true
            userWantsToRemoveDeleteButton = false
            collectionView.reloadData()

            doneEditingButton.enabled = true
    }

    func deleteAssignment(sender: UIButton) {
        let i : Int = (sender.layer.valueForKey("index")) as! Int
        AssignmentManager.deleteAssignment(i)

        NSUserDefaultsManager.synchronize()

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's happening because userDelete becomes true and then button is shown in every cell. You should remember on which cell user pressed. So maybe add tag to the cell (indexPath.row), and then in deleteMode function call reload method. Then in cellForRow method check if `selectedTag` is equal to the indexPath.row and show button if it is, else hide it.
This is just a quick example how you can do it....

Comment: so would I add a tag to the cell in my deleteMode function or in cellForRow method?